# Google Cloud Build windows builder error "Failed to get external IP address: Could not get external NAT IP from list"

Tags: containers, google-cloud-build, docker-for-windows

I am trying to implement automatic deployments for my Windows Kubernetes container app. I'm following instructions from the Google's [windows-builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/windows-builder), but the trigger quickly fails with this error at about 1.5 minutes in:

```
2021/12/16 19:30:06 Set ingress firewall rule successfully
2021/12/16 19:30:06 Failed to get external IP address: Could not get external NAT IP from list
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/[my-project-id]/windows-builder" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

The container, gcr.io/[my-project-id]/windows-builder, definitely exists and it's located in the same GCP project as the Cloud Build trigger just as the windows-builder documentation commanded.

I structured my code based off of Google's [docker-windows example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/windows-builder/images/docker-windows). Here is my repository file structure:

```
repository
   cloudbuild.yaml
   builder.ps1
   worker
      Dockerfile
```

Here is my cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
# WORKER
- name: 'gcr.io/[my-project-id]/windows-builder'
  args: [ '--command', 'powershell.exe -file build.ps1' ]

# OPTIONS
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

Here is my builder.ps1:

```
docker build -t gcr.io/[my-project-id]/test-worker ./worker;
if ($?) {
  docker push gcr.io/[my-project-id]/test-worker;
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/[my-project-id]/test-windows-node-base:onbuild
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicated the steps from GitHub and got the same error. It is throwing `Failed to get external IP address...` error because the External IP address of the VM is disabled by default in the [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/8c5d1ea98e86cd25823e83b1f436aa13d359a775/windows-builder/builder/main.go#L37). I was able to build it successfully by adding `'--create-external-ip', 'true'` in `cloudbuild.yaml`.

Here is my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/windows-builder'
  args: [  '--create-external-ip', 'true',
           '--command', 'powershell.exe -file build.ps1' ]
```

Comment: Thank you! That got rid of the error and the build completes. But oddly enough, the container never gets updated in container registry. I checked the build logs and the only thing that looks like an error is a message that says "The system cannot find the path specified." I assume it's talking about the build.ps1 file but I'm not sure. Any idea what could be going wrong here? Did your container actually get updated when you ran the job?

Comment: @MikeH yes it did. See this for your reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcDAj.png. I suggest you start from scratch to have a clean slate. Also if it helped you, please consider upvoting my answer.

Comment: you solved my original issue so I'll mark this as complete. Thank you for your help!